# Cell width too big for tableview width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a programmatic tableview nested in a caraousel, but when it displays, the programmatic cell is always set wider than the tableview its in. If I print the carousel item width, tableview width and cell width I get: 281, 281, 320(iphone5 screen width). I tried adding constraints to the cell but keep getting nil errors, I believe because the cell hasn't been made yet. So I'm not sure where to put the constraints so that I stop getting these errors, I only need the cell content view width to match the tableview width, but how do I get the tableview width in my custom cell which has been made programmatically? Heres my current code without any constraints:

TableView:

```
import UIKit

class SplitterCarouselItemTableView: UITableView {

    var splitter: BillSplitter?

    required init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle, splitter: BillSplitter) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        self.splitter = splitter
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView() {

        if Platform.isPhone {
            let tableViewBackground = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: splitter?.image as! Data, scale:1.0))
            self.backgroundView = tableViewBackground
            tableViewBackground.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            tableViewBackground.frame = self.frame
        }

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.separatorStyle = .none
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    tableView.register(SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell")

    let cell: SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell") as! SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell
    var item = ((allBillSplitters[tableView.tag].items)?.allObjects as! [Item])[indexPath.row]
    if allBillSplitters[tableView.tag].isMainBillSplitter {
        getMainBillSplitterItems(splitter: allBillSplitters[tableView.tag])
        item = mainBillSplitterItems[indexPath.row]
    }
    let count = item.billSplitters?.count

    if count! > 1 {
        cell.name!.text = "\(item.name!)\nsplit \(count!) ways"
        cell.price!.text = "£\(Double(item.price)/Double(count!))"

    } else {
        cell.name!.text = item.name!
        cell.price!.text = "£\(item.price)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

Cell:

```
import UIKit

class SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var name: UILabel!
    var price: UILabel!
    var view: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:)")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell")

        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        let width = Int(contentView.bounds.width)
        let height = Int(contentView.bounds.height)

        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: width, height: height - 4 ))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        let viewHeight = Int(view.bounds.height)
        let viewWidth = Int(view.bounds.width)

        price = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: viewWidth - 80, y: 0, width: 75, height: viewHeight))
        price.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        price.textAlignment = .right

        name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: width, height: viewHeight))
        name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        name.numberOfLines = 0

        view.addSubview(name)
        view.addSubview(price)

        contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

I understand the init shouldn't be filled with all that code and will be extracted later. Its just there until i resolve the width issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width` to get exact width of screen.

Comment: You should not register your cell in `cellForRowAt:indexPath` - perhaps that is causing the issue. Register the cell with your tableView in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs thanks i have moved it but nothing has changed.

Comment: @iphonic i have tried adding this constraint in awakeFromNib in the custom cell but nothing changed.

Comment: How are you init'ing the UITableView?  It is correct that the Cell and Table have the same width.  You shouldn't have to do anything to get these to match.  Are you adding the TableView in a storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @dmorrow The tableview init is in the top of my question's code, but the cell and the tableview don't have the same width, the tableview is 281 and the cell is 320(same as the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is that the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` method indirectly calls `init(frame:)` on your `UITableViewCell` class.  There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. Override `init(frame:)` in `SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell` and set your width there when you call `super.init(frame:)`
2. Modify your `cell.frame` in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method

Using Autolayout is problematic with UITableView cells.  You don't want to go messing with all the subviews there.

Comment: thank you, i needed to set the frame in the cell's init as it wasnt working in the cellForRowAt

Comment: there's no `init(frame: CGRect)` method for `UITableViewCell` and setting frame in coder initializer does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
    cell.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(Int(cell.frame.minX)),
                        y: CGFloat(Int(cell.frame.minY)),
                        width: tableView.frame.width,
                        height: cell.frame.height)
```

to your

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This fixed the problem for me.

My UITableViewController and UITableViewCell were done programmatically

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad Grab your tableView Outlet  or  your tableView Instance if you made it programmatically, then access to rowHeight and give an Value to it :  Like This code Below:

```
enter code here
private let MenuTableView:UITableView = {
   
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tableView.register(FoodTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FoodTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return tableView
    
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(MenuTableView)
    MenuTableView.rowHeight = 50
   
}
```